# Count values of data-attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, count, custom-data-attribute

I have list like this.

```
<li data-pet="cat"></li>
<li data-pet="cat"></li>
<li data-pet="cat"></li>
<li data-pet="dog"></li>
```

Using jQuery how can I grab the value of the data-attributes to count if the same value appears more than once.

I then want to append a span to first list element with that value.

Result should look like this.

```
<li data-pet="cat"><span class="first"></span></li>
<li data-pet="cat"></li>
<li data-pet="cat"></li>
<li data-pet="dog"></li>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a possible implementation

```
(function() {  
    var pets = {};
    $('li[data-pet]').each(function() {
        var li = $(this),
            pet = li.data('pet');

        if (!pets[pet]) {  
            pets[pet] = { firstnode: li, count : 1 }
        }
        else {
            pets[pet]['count'] = pets[pet]['count'] + 1;
        }
    });

    $.map(pets, function(obj) {     
        if (obj.count > 1) {
          obj.firstnode.append('<span class="first">'+ obj.count +'</span>');
        }
    });
}());
```

html

```
<li data-pet="cat">cat</li>
<li data-pet="cat">cat</li>
<li data-pet="cat">cat</li>
<li data-pet="dog">dog</li>
<li data-pet="elephant">elephant</li>
<li data-pet="elephant">elephant</li>
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HJ6gF/6/

Comment: Excellent. Including the total was nice touch. I will also that aswell. Thanks.

Comment: I changed a bit the implementation so the code is more performant - no real need to read a selection of li nodes inside $.map function.

Answer (score 0):

A way for this would be (you should optimize/neaten it according to your situation ofcourse):

```
var selector = "cat";
var selectorCount = 0;

$("li[data-pet="+selector+"]").each(function() {
    selectorCount++;
});

if(selectorCount > 1) {
    $("li[data-pet="+selector+"]").each(function() {
        $(this).html("<span class=\"first\"></span>");
        break;
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a `.each` when you just `.length` on selector?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Two problems. First there is syntax error and also why variable called "cat". I want get all data-attributed regardless of value and then count them to determine if there is more than once occurrence of it.

Comment: @jamjam: Hence the "you should optimize/neaten it according to your situation". You aren't providing any context information on your issue so I was unable to tailor the code to your needs. You should be able to deduct what you need to change from this code...

Answer (score 0):

```
var tarr = [];
$('li').each(function() {
   tarr.push($(this).attr('data-pet'))
});
var count = $.unique(tarr).length;
```

Comment: From the jQuery API Docs: 
*"Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, **not strings or numbers**."*

Answer (score 0):

```
<li data-pet="cat"/>
<li data-pet="cat"/>
<li data-pet="cat"/>
<li data-pet="dog"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var dataPets = [];

    $('li').each( function( index )
    {
        if ( $.inArray( $(this).attr( "data-pet" ) , dataPets ) )
        {
            $(this).append( "First" );
        }

        dataPets[index] = $(this).attr( "data-pet" );
    });

</script>
```