# Counting through data-* producing double the expected results

Tags: jquery, html

[Count values of data-attribute with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176593/count-values-of-data-attribute-with-jquery)

I'm using the accepted answer as a base for some statistics I'm running on a table.  The function below, which I re-purposed for my use, counts double what I expect it to count.  For example I have 20 `td` with a `data-vaction` of "deny".  It counts 40.  For the record I have the object declared outside of the function for debugging at the moment.  It's as if the entire process runs twice, or counts twice per `each`.

Jquery:

```
var vactions = {};
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('td[data-vaction]').each(function() {
    var td = $(this), 
        vaction = td.data('vaction'); 

    if (!vactions[vaction]) {  
        vactions[vaction] = {count : 1 } 
    }
    else {
        vactions[vaction]['count'] = vactions[vaction]['count'] + 1;
    }
  });
});
```

example Row:

```
<td>[<A class="doThings" HREF="http://somewhere.com">3787</A>]<!--entry--> </td>
<td>  2013-01-25    </td>
<td class="daysAgo">0 </td>
<td>  Item    </td>
<td>  Description  </td>
<td align="RIGHT" > Count    </td>
<td> Vendor    </td>
<td></td> <td style="font-size:10px;" data-col="workcenter"> Assembly</td>
<td  colspan="1"><!--//RGA--></td>
<td data-col="closed">      Open    </td>
<td> 0  </td>
<td colspan="2" class="vendorAct" style="background:#b20000;color:white;" data-col="vaction" data-vaction="unresolved" >    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this question, delete if you want.

For the answer:  I had the `script` inside of a `div` that moved on the page during an event that fired on ready.  It was causing it to be ready twice I assume.  Regardless because of the variable was declared outside of the document ready, I was ruining my own statistics.